# Unable to trigger lambda for specific channel and specific event (StartChannel)

Tags: aws-event-bridge

We have created a Lambda that is triggered by an Eventbridge. This Eventbridge should respond to a Medialive channel going live. We use this to turn on a series of alerts when the channel is streaming, an then, on a separate lambda, to turn the alerts off when the channel stops.

We where able to trigger the lambda following this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/option-2.html). This was the suggested event pattern for the eventbridge:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.medialive"
  ],
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:111122223333:channel:1234567"
  ] 
}
```

The problem there is that we need to add the specific event name as well for the lambda to trigger when we want it to. This would be the event:

```
 "eventName": ["StartChannel"]
```

We have tried several patterns but none works once we add the eventName. Like this one:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.medialive"
  ],
  "resources":["arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:111122223333:channel:1234567"],
  "detail-type": ["StartChannel"]
}
```

or this one:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.medialive"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["medialive.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["StartChannel"]
  },
  "resources": ["arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:111122223333:channel:1234567"]
}
```

We also tried using "AWS API Call via Cloudtrail" but it was no good since it didn't specified the event, only a change of state:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "detail-type": "MediaLive Channel State Change",
  "source": "aws.medialive",
  "account": "111122223333",
  "time": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "region": "us-east-2",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:111122223333:channel:1234567"],
  "detail": {
    "pipeline": "1",
    "message": "Pipeline started for channel"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We finally got it:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.medialive"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["medialive.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["StartChannel"],
    "responseElements": {
      "arn": [{
        "prefix": "arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:111122223333:channel:1234567"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

That did the trick.
Cheers